# Inexpensive vehicular guided tour of Sydney

Tags: australia, guides, sydney, accessibility

We're looking for a guided tour of Sydney. We initially considered the hop-on, hop-off tour bus for Sydney, but $40 for ordinary fares, $30 for concession was a bit steep. Another possibility I considered was the free walking tour of Sydney. However, the other person is elderly and couldn't keep up with the mainly young people it attracts.

Is there anything reasonably inexpensive and suitable for a limited mobility person? Ideally, it'd operate on weekends. Something that starts from and ends in the Central Coast might be an option.

Comment: Just buy an all-zones public transport day pass, and make your own way around?

Comment: @Gagravarr Cheap, but not very guided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a lot worse than the [Captain Cook Hop-On, Hop-Off Cruise](https://www.captaincook.com.au/sydney-harbour-cruises/hop-on-hop-off/). The ferries are all wheelchair-accessible and there's some basic guide-style commentary as well.

The list price for the all-you-can-ride 24 hour pass is also $40 per head, but they've got good deals with many attractions so you can get, for example, the pass and Sydney Tower or Sea Life Aquarium for $55 combined, vs. something like $80 separately.  Cheaper yet, you can buy a return ticket for a suitably distant attraction (say, Manly at $18) and then [pick a service](https://www.captaincook.com.au/sydney-harbour-cruises/ferries/taronga-zoo-express/) that happens to visit all the points you want to see -- they're the same boats!  Alternatively, you can pay a bit or a lot more and get meals, entertainment etc on board with Captain Cook or any of a number of competitors, although (IMHO) these are not great value.

The even-cheaper alternative is to just use regular public transport [Sydney Ferries](http://www.transport.nsw.gov.au/customers/ferries/sydney-ferries) to explore.  With an [Opal card](https://www.opal.com.au/) the fare caps out at $15/day, your elderly companion may qualify for the $2.50/day cap, and everybody can ride all they want for $2.50 on Sundays.  These, too, are all wheelchair-friendly.